# When I tried to mint NFTs using cmv3 (from metaplex) in Solana using the ui and sugar-cli tool, I get 0x99 error. What is 0x99 error?

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I am using the `sugar-cli 1.1.2-alpha+CMv3` to deploy the candymachine. Also, I used a cmv3 mint site to mint different NFTs for different guard groups. The site worked for a long time and for the past three weeks we are getting 0x99 error while minting.

I could not find `0x99` error means. Also, I saw metaplex has introduced a new guard group `token2022Payment`. Is there some update which I might have missed?

The error is shown below:

```
MetaplexError: CandyGuardProgram > Unknown Program Error
>> Source: Program > CandyGuardProgram [Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g]
>> Problem: The program [CandyGuardProgram] at address [Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g] raised an error that is not recognized by the programs registered by the SDK.
>> Solution: Unfortunately, you will need to check the unparsed error below to investigate what went wrong. To get more helpful error messages, ensure the program that failed is registered by the SDK and provides an "errorResolver" method.

Caused By: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 4: custom program error: 0x99


....
```

I tried removing the guard from the candymachine and minting the NFTs to see the same error. I tried minting from the console. I tried minting from the UI. I also tried minting on different versions of sugar (`2.3.0`, `1.1.2-alpha+CMv3`, `sugar-cmv3-alpha.2`). None of it worked.

I could not find the mention of `0x99` anywhere in the docs or community.